# Is it possible to bake a hologram in blender?

Tags: baking

What I'm thinking of is having a simple emissive texture for a surface. However, rather than a single emissive texture, it is an emissive texture for each viewing angle.
Similar to how a hologram works, in that a series of images exist and as you view the hologram from different angles the picture changes.

Much like how you can use a 360 image to create a better lighting effect, except there would be one texture for a series of viewing angles.
I understand this would result in a very very large object but I'm thinking of using some mpeg style compression to reduce it so it can be loaded into a shader buffer. I think this concept might be called a lumigraph but I'm not sure about that.

**Update**

So after having done some more research I think [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/2dyn8n/baking_the_glossy_incident_rays_to_render_camera/cjupu8a?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) is sort of what I want:

> Render out an ordinary render, and have the renderer deliver glossy
> direct and glossy colour passes. Use the compositor to multiply those
> two to get an image that has the light you would get from the glossy
> incident rays. Then create a new image texture and add it into your
> Cycles material to set it as the active texture. Now, go to texture
> paint mode and set your viewport render mode to Texture. I couldn't
> get Apply Camera Image to work this time, so I just saved out my
> render result to an external file and told Blender to do a Quick Edit
> with a resolution of 1920x1080 (my render resolution) from the
> viewpoint of my camera. Then I just pasted my render result into the
> temporary document in the image editor, flattened the image, saved the
> image, hopped back into Blender and hit Apply. Here's the result that
> I get. Of course, make sure to save out your texture independently of
> your Blender file, or Blender will eat it for breakfast without
> warning you.

But then using the Linked answer, to make lots of those textures.
I also think [this answer](https://blenderartists.org/t/is-it-possible-to-bake-all-lighting-detail-based-on-camera-position-angle/641774) is something like what I want but again requiring the linked answer to sort out having multiple camera angles.

**Second update**
This [other post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/script-skew-camera-in-game-engine) seems to be pretty much what I'm asking for:
[Script skew camera in game engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/script-skew-camera-in-game-engine)

Comment: Sounds like a sprite sheet to me https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5829/how-can-i-export-a-blender-model-as-a-sprite-sheet

Comment: So very similar to what you linked except how would you do this for a texture rather than a sprite? With a sprite, I can imagine an issue with partial occlusion of other objects.